# How do I prevent a null trigger of an AJAX event?

Tags: jquery, ajax, onchange

With the following jQuery code I have created a drop down that updates the page however I believe that when it changes `#content` with the returned result it is counting it as a `change` event and pulling the `#sidebar` info.

```
<script>
var get_pages_load_options = { 
    target:        '#content',
    data: {ajaxtype: 'content'},
    beforeSubmit:  function() {
        console.debug('beforeSubmit');
    },
    success: function() {
        console.debug('successful');
    }
};
$("#content").on('change','.get_pages',function(){
    var submit_page = $(this).attr('rel');
    var form_url = $("#"+submit_page).attr('action');
    console.debug(submit_page+" & "+form_url);
    $("#"+submit_page).ajaxForm(get_pages_load_options);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: form_url,
        data: {ajaxtype: "side"},
        success: function(data) {
            console.debug(data);
            $("#sidebar_menu").html(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The HTML is as follows for `#content`:

```
<div id="content" class="content">
    <h1>Game Updates</h1>
    <form action="/gameplay/updates/" id="submit_page" name="submit_page" class="get_pages" method="post">
        <select name="year" class="get_pages" rel="submit_page">
            <option value="2012">2012 -- v1.7.0 - v2.0.0</option>
            <option value="2011">2011 -- v1.5.3 - v1.6.0</option>
            <option value="2010">2010 -- v1.3.3 - v1.5.2</option>
            <option value="2009">2009 -- v1.1.4 - v1.3.2</option>
            <option value="2008">2008 -- v0.6.0 - v1.1.3</option>
            <option value="2007">2007 -- v0.1.x - v0.5.5</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    /** Update Logs **/
    <br/><br/>
    <p>
        -----------<br />
        Thank you,<br />
        Admin deth4uall
    </p>
</div>
```

Do you know how I can prevent the second firing of change. Thanks!

EDIT: I do have a regular version that is default with the above supposed to be overwriting the below functionality:

```
$("#content").on('change','.get_pages',function(){
    var submit_page = $(this).attr('rel');
    $("#"+submit_page).submit();
});
```

Comment: if you are using jQuery 1.3.2+, replace livequery with live. If you are using jQuery 1.4+ replace it with http://api.jquery.com/delegate , and finally, if you are using jQuery 1.7+ replace it with http://api.jquery.com/on . Else, we'll have to look at the documentation for livequery.

Comment: When I start using `on()` again, only every other option activates the ajax. I am using 1.7.2

Comment: Are you using the correct syntax for a `.on` delegated event? `$("#content").on("change",".get_pages",function(){...});`

Comment: Still getting `submit_page & /gameplay/updates/ jquery.ajax.js:83` and `undefined & undefined jquery.ajax.js:83` in debug logs

Comment: that doesn't make a lot of sense... but ohwell, back to livequery as it seems to have the least problems at this point. Is that script block inside of the div you are changing/replacing?

Comment: Yes, it is within the div being replaced, which is why I am trying to figure out what I can do lol.

Comment: Before you append it, remove all script tags from it, as you don't need to re-execute them. First try `...html($(data).find("script").remove().end());` for the easy approach, if that doesn't work, we'll have to resort to regexp more than likely.

Comment: hmm... Why not just place an if statement that returns out of the function if the values are undefined?

Comment: Oh wow, derp! Thanks, I would have so done that in PHP but not in JavaScript because I am still working out how to do it. If you post that as an answer I will accept :) I added `if (form_url.length > 0) { /** Do the ajax **/ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are undefined, simply return out of the function.

```
$("#content").on('change','.get_pages',function(){
    var submit_page = $(this).attr('rel');
    var form_url = $("#"+submit_page).attr('action');
    if (!submit_page || !form_url) {
        return;
    }
    //console.debug(submit_page+" & "+form_url);
    $("#"+submit_page).ajaxForm(get_pages_load_options);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: form_url,
        data: {ajaxtype: "side"},
        success: function(data) {
            //console.debug(data);
            $("#sidebar_menu").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you have been an awesome help today with all the issues I have been having, been learning quite a bit about JavaScript :)

Comment: what does form_url and submit_page contain exactly when it should be not grabbing content?

Comment: submit_page grabs the `rel=""` attribute from the `.get_pages` select and then uses that to look up the id of the form to get the `action=""` from the form being submitted.

Comment: The change event should not be getting triggered at all unless you are triggering it either manually with the mouse or keyboard, or through javascript. I would investigate from that angle.

Comment: Yes, I think it is working correctly now but that was after I added the `.length > 0`, rather it shouldn't be putting city hall info.

Comment: I don't see the change event happening at all until it is supposed to happen.

Comment: I think adding that check and going back to livequery fixed it, awesome! Thanks again!